# TicTacToe win conditions problems

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, tic-tac-toe

New programmer here, writing a Tictactoe game using Java on Eclipse.

I have problems with my win conditions I think. It comes up with the error:
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at Game.NoughtsCrosses.(NoughtsCrosses.java:106)
        at Game.Main.main(Main.java:5)

Here is my win conditions bit. It's not well made imo, but I'm having problems when compiling. Can anyone spot why? Ty!!

I have squares set up in a 3x3 grid, 0 -> 8. Each button has its own text which is set to X or O when clicked by each player.

winconditions code:

```
if (square[0].getText().equals(square[1].getText()) && square[1].getText().equals(square[2].getText()) != square[0].getText().isEmpty()) {
    win = true;
}
```

[Full Pastebin of code](http://pastebin.com/JwXM4Vjt)

Thanks again :) Any questions, I can elaborate :D

Comment: 1) There is no need to add the major tag in the title. 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: FYI this is actually a _run-time error_ not a _compile-time error_.

Comment: just wanted to let you know I updated my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I took the code that you provided and after significant finagling was able to make a fully functioning Tic-Tac-Toe game. You were mostly on the right track with what you were doing you just needed to first begin with a design.

In my NoughtsCrosses class I have the following:

- class Action implements ActionListener

  - This has a JButton attribute that I pass in through a constructor
  - In the actionPerformed

    - set the text
    - disable the button
    - increment the counter
    - check if someone wins

      - If there is a winner or draw game ends set the "Play again?" text
      - else call the changeTurn function
- class Reset implements ActionListenter

  - This has a JButton attribute that I pass in through a constructor
  - In the actionPerformed

    - I call the resetGame function
- function changeTurn
- function resetGame
- function checkForWinners

as a hint, this is my implementation of the Action class and an example of the constructor I mentioned

```
class Action implements ActionListener{ 
 private JButton button;
 public Action(JButton button){ 
  this.button = button; 
 } 
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
   button.setText(letter); 
   button.setEnabled(false); 
   counter++; 
   boolean gameOver = checkForWinners(); 
   if(!gameOver) 
    changeTurn(); 
   else{ 
    newgame.setText("Play again?"); 
    newgame.addActionListener(resetButton); 
   } 
 } 
}
```

a call like `new Action(square[i])` is what you need to make this work. 
Note: the `resetButton` is of the `Reset` class I mention above much like the `Action` class it has the same construct that I passed `newgame` into.

Comment: here is a basic design for the program you want. As I said I have a fully working version so ask me if you have questions implementing it

Comment: Thank you so much, you're a life saver :D Did you change much about the GUI or does that all look fine? Did you keep the buttons in a 1-dimensional array or change it two a multi-dimensional array?

Comment: I kept them in a one dimensional array. The only thing I changed on the GUI is added the missing ActionListener to reset the game the rest was just fine!

Comment: Ah okay. At least I'm okay with Swing :P Okay I've been messing around, seems to work now. Excuse the noob question but I can get the game to input one square, changing it to an X, but then it doesnt counter++ (I think, no player change) and can't select another button. CAn I ask how you went about your function changeTurn? Sorry, am new to this :D

Comment: No problem. With my implementation I incremented the counter in the Action class then I checked for winners or a draw and then called the changeTurn which has this code from what you wrote:`if (counter % 2 == 0){ 
                player = 1; letter = "X"; 
                  
            } 
            else{ 
                    player = 2; letter = "O";  
            } 
            playergo.setText("It is Player " + player + "'s Turn");`

Comment: Ok done a little more editing. Aside from many "syntax errors: enter } to finish classbody" (which I seem to have many of :P), I've updated my pastebin with my progress, I seem to be having problems with calling the functions if checking win combos and checking resetTurn or something. Thank you so much for all your help, how can I ever repay you :D

Comment: Its getting pretty good. You still need to pass the button into your `Action` instances like so `square[i].addActionListener(new Action(square[i]));` also with the way you have it setup you need your `player` and `counter` variables as globals (in the same place you have your swing objects). Some bigger things are that `changeTurn` and `WinCombos` aren't classes they are functions so they should look like `public void changeTurn(){..code..}`  (void means you arent returning any thing) and `public boolean WinCombos(){..code..}` (boolean means you are returning a boolean [true/false])

Comment: make sure you have a return statement in `WinCombos` that returns `win`. Also the restartGame on line 113 must be initialized it is an `ActionListener` a lot like the `Action` class i.e. all the same setup except it resets the game in its own `actionPerformed` function. I had `resetGame` as a global variable in mine. it was equal to `new Reset(newgame);`

Comment: please also remember to select my answer!

Comment: Hey dude, thank you for all your help. Love that the programming community is so friendly to newbies :) It's currently feeling a bit better but still got some troubles - when I press the buttons, nothing happens. Have I forgotten a crucial piece of code?! [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/JwXM4Vjt)

Comment: I just tested the code that you have and it works just fine for me... the only modifications I made was to add a final `}` and put the winning lines variable inside actionPerformed.

Comment: This is the final version I tested your code as [NoughtsCrosess](http://pastebin.com/sJ3NUQiE). The final version I had created personally is this [NoughtsCrosses](http://pastebin.com/eCsPjmzB)

Answer (score 3):

It looks like one of the squares text is null. One thing that is important to remember is that an empty string is not the same thing as null. In java, if you haven't specifically assigned a value to a String then it will be null. To fix this, you will want to explicitly set each squares text to `""` (an empty string) when you set up your game board.

Comment: OP says "Each button has its own text which is set to X or O when clicked by each player."  That may imply you are correct, and that it is one of the unclicked buttons that is causing the problem.

Comment: @rossum yeah that combined with the `java.lang.NullPointerException` makes me fairly confident that is the problem

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to implement this type of solution, then simplify the job for yourself. Based on the tiny snippet of code I see above, it looks like you're really over-complicating the job you have to do.

```
char cell0 = //get that char, be it X or O
char cell1 = //
...
char cell8 = //
```

Now you can compare cells one by one to determine a victory. Your board game is set up as follows:

```
0 1 2
3 4 5
6 7 8
```

So you can just go in order:

```
Horizontal Solutions:
(cell0 == cell1 && cell0 == cell2)
(cell3 == cell4 && cell3 == cell5)
(cell6 == cell7 && cell6 == cell8)

Vertical Solutions
(cell0 == cell3 && cell0 == cell6)
//And so on

Cross Solutions:
(cell0 == cell4 && cell0 == cell8)
(cell2 == cell4 && cell2 == cell6)
```

This will check for your victory conditon.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have a surplus of braces in your code so that the statements in the question actually appear in an instance initializer block of the class `NoughtsCrosses` but none of the `JButton` components have been initialized yet as instance initializers are invoked *before* constructors which is where the `JButton` instantiated exist (but never called). When you attempt to invoke `getText` on the first element of the array `square`, a 
`NullPointerException` is thrown.

To fix remove the additional braces to that the code is enclosed in the preceding `ActionListener`

```
class Action implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       // existing code here
/// }    remove
//}      remove
// {     remove

    // win conditions. if true, set win==true; else set win
    // here is where the compilation error is, next line
    if (square[0].getText() == square[1].getText() ...) { 
      win = true;
    } //etc
} <-- add this
```

Comment: Thank you! Just got rid of those. Now it loads fine, got another error or two but at least I can see whats happening now and start taking care of it. Thank you again :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your win-condition check is not within your `actionPerformed` code, but on the class level, hence it is possibly called before the window is populated with your buttons.

Try placing the check inside the `actionPerformed` like this: http://pastebin.com/xRViSUzy

Answer (score 0):

What is the scope (most simply, which curly braces) is the problematic line inside of?

It was a bit tricky to tell based on your indentation, but it appears to me that your "if" was not inside a method (e.g. the constructor). I would guess that you intended this line and the ones around them to be executed after the lines in the body of your constructor where the squares are initialized. Instead, these lines are being run beforehand and therefore the call to "new" haven't been run yet.

I think that if you do some restructuring to move these conditions into your constructor or into another method that you call *after* construction then things will look a lot better.

Hope that helps.